# What is the fiqh ruling on lost property in mosques?

Tags: fiqh, masjid, property

I'd like to know the ruling or if there are different opinions and cases for lost property (لُقَطَة) -books, keys, smartphones, etc.- which was found in mosques?

It happens often that people when leaving a mosque for example take the wrong pair of shoes -unintentionally- (so I don't mean cases these are stolen), so their own shoes might stay in the mosque can the person finding them if he was the owner of the other shoes take them instead?
Or more general if you found something that might have an owner in a mosque should you announce it and if so how? Can you use it etc.?

Are there differences of opinion and differences between mosques for example [the three mosques](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/20/2)?

Comment: According to [this](https://sunnah.com/urn/211560) hadith, if one lost something, they shouldn't announce it in the mosque which I'm not sure if it includes lost property inside mosques but since that's not anything to with worship, per the hadith, one shouldn't announce it in the mosque since according to [Imam Nawawi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Nawawi) in his [commentary of Sahih Muslim](http://hadith.al-islam.com/Loader.aspx?pageid=261), it leads to the voice being raised.

Comment: @Armaan this applies for those who raise their voices asking for something they lost, I'm talking about the opposite situation, when you find something somebody else lost...

Comment: Well I suppose if one did find something belonging to someone else in the mosque, they might not know where the person is and therefore ask for the person by announcing it in the mosque which is related to worldly matters and not worship.