# How to interpret the ahadith on making lost property anouncmenents in mosques?

Tags: fiqh, hadith-interpretation, masjid

This question might deliver a hint or partial answer of my other question [What is the fiqh ruling on lost property in mosques?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/what-is-the-fiqh-ruling-on-lost-property-in-mosques) and it has some relation with my former question: [Do mosques in Islam have a sacredness and how is it defined?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49670/do-mosques-in-islam-have-a-sacredness-and-how-is-it-defined). But here I might ask about some more details about the specific ahadith on the topic of "Lost property anouncments in mosques?"

There are some ahadith on this topic like:

- > The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: If anyone hears a man crying out in the mosque about something he has lost, he should say: May Allah not restore it to you, for the mosques were not built for this. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/98), [Sunan abi Daowd](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/83) and [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/4/33))
- > Sulaiman b. Buraida reported on the authority of his father that when the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) had said prayer a man stood up and said:
  >   Who called for a red camel? (Upon this) the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: May it not be restored to you! The mosques are built for what they are meant. (Sahih Muslim [1](https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/100) & [2](https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/101) and [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/4/31))

These ahadith can be understood as a prohibition for seeking something lost in a mosque and/or for announcing a lost maybe even for raising the voice in a mosque.

- Which of these possible conclusions actually apply?
- Are they restricted on doing this inside a mosque?
- Does this apply for humans too for example a father/mother seeking his/her son/daughter/child who has got lost in the crowd during their stay inside a mosque?